# Cross reference names on spreadsheets to get specific data points (looping through an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets. Test Data has 3-4k entries of many columns of data and Order Changes has no data at all. I would like to search two specific columns on Test Data, a column of names and a column of yes or no. If column two of Test Data contains a 'yes' in the cell then the name of that person would be placed into a cell on order changes.

This is what I have so far:

```
    function isThreshold(){
  
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Data");
  var cdata = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order Changes");
  var lc = data.getLastColumn();
  var lookUp = data.getRange(1,6,3,2).getValues();
  
  lookUp.forEach(var info in lookUp){
  
  }
  Logger.log(lookUp);
}
```

I probably shouldn't loop through that many entries but I don't know of any other way. Should I combine the forEach loop with an if loop to get the desired result or use some other method?

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your script and `Big has 3-4k entries of many columns of data and small has no data at all. I would like to search two specific columns on Big, a column of names and a column of yes and no. If column two of Big contains a 'yes' in the cell the name of that person would be placed into a cell on small.`? I cannot understand about `Big` and `small`.

Comment: I just used big and small as substitutes for Test Data and Order Changes. Test Data = Big and Order Changes = small. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you update your question? By this, it will help users understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. From your script of `var lookUp = data.getRange(1,6,3,2).getValues()`, in the sheet "Test Data", the data range is "F1:G3"? You want to search `yes` from only 3 rows? If it's so, the two specific columns of `I would like to search two specific columns on Test Data` is the columns "F" and "G"? I cannot understand about the structure of the sheet "Test Data" from your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: I was only using "F1:G3" to decrease the time it took for the logs to populate. on the final version "F1:G" or .getRange(1,6,data.getLastRow(),lc); to search through all of column F and all of column G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "F1:G" of sheet "Test Data".
- You want to search `yes` from the column "G" and when the column "G" is `yes`, you want to put the value of the column "F" to the sheet "Order Changes".

#### Modification points:

- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be declared one time.
- In this case, you can retrieve the values from the range of `"F1:G" + data.getLastRow()` of "Test Data", and create the array for putting to the sheet "Order Changes", and put it.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function isThreshold(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getSheetByName("Test Data");
  var cdata = ss.getSheetByName("Order Changes");
  var valuesOfTestData = data.getRange("F1:G" + data.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var valuesForOrderChanges = valuesOfTestData.reduce((ar, [f, g]) => {
    if (g.toLowerCase() == "yes") ar.push([f]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (valuesForOrderChanges.length > 0) {
    cdata.getRange(1, 1, valuesForOrderChanges.length, valuesForOrderChanges[0].length).setValues(valuesForOrderChanges);
    // or cdata.getRange(cdata.getLastRow() + 1, 1, valuesForOrderChanges.length, valuesForOrderChanges[0].length).setValues(valuesForOrderChanges);
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, from your question, it supposes that the columns "F" and "G" are the value of name and `yes` or `no`.

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. How do I see what information was populated with Logger.log?

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. When you want to check the values for putting to destination, for example, please put `Logger.log(valuesForOrderChanges)` to the last line of the function `isThreshold`.